# How to calculate count and first occurrence of list data?

Tags: pandas, list

I have a list which has types of cars,

`a = ['Car_1','Car_1','Car_1','Car_2','Car_3','Car_3']`

I should be able to create an output of 2 lists from the above list,

```
result_count = [1,0,0,1,1,0] #Whenever new car type is present in list, make it 1
result_count = [1,2,3,1,1,2] #Count each car type
```

How can I easily achieve this without using for loops? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, using a pandas dataframe

for #1 we can use `.drop_duplicates`

for #2 we can use `groupby` and `cumcount`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cars' : a})

one = (~df['cars'].duplicated()).astype(int).tolist() # Thanks to Erfan
two = (df.groupby('cars').cumcount() + 1).tolist()

print(one)

[1 0 0 1 1 0]

print(two)

[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2]
```